# Where the summoned creatures come from?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-series

In Elder Scrolls Oblivion and Morrowind you can summon a skeleton or a zombie to aid you in battle but where they come from?

I find logical other creatures such as imps, atronachs and dremoras are summonable, they live in another plane and this could be some kind of "pact" you entablish with them. I just don't know where those skeletons or zombies come from.

Comment: The Skyrim Dawnguard DLC explains that summoned undead come from the [Soul Cairn](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Soul_Cairn_(Dawnguard)) plane. Since Morrow/Oblivion are in the same universe, it's probably the same

Comment: @Wondercricket you should post your comment as an answer so I can accept it, that's exactly the explanation to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot say if this was ever explained in either Morrowind or Oblivion, but it is later explained in the Skyrim DLC Dawnguard. The [Plane of Oblivion](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Planes_of_Oblivion)  you are looking for is [Soul Cairn](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Soul_Cairn_(Dawnguard)).

> It is a plane of Oblivion inhabited by souls and undead
>
> **Background**
>
> When a soul is trapped in a Black Soul Gem and its energy used to power an enchantment, the remnant—the soul itself—is sent to the Soul Cairn. It is a place devoid of life—the only beings that exist there are souls, undead and the rulers of the realm, the Ideal Masters

Answer (score 1):

Summoning is a skill in the conjuration school of magic. The skill summon, will summon creatures from other planes. So yes you are still summoning the zombies and skeletons from another plane.

Source:
[summoning creatures from other planes](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Conjuration)

Answer (score 1):

All summoned creatures come from one plane of Oblivion or another. This is why the symbol associated with the conjuration school is an Oblivion Gate.[image]